# Выбор формата сообщений: XML, JSON, Protocol Buffers для протокола

Tags: xml, c, json

Поставлена задача разработать протокол уведомления двух устройств. Оба устройства подключены друг к другу по сети (Ethernet). На одном устройстве Linux, на другом Real-time OS. Нужно создать протокол, по которому устройства будут уведомлять друг друга о событиях. Реализация запланирована на C поверх TCP/IP.

На данный момент выбор такой:

- свой собственный формат,
- XML или JSON,
- Protocol buffers.

Вопрос в том, что

1. проще в использовании,
2. легче в поддержке, развитии,
3. проще в реализации?

Comment: Как вариант - http://msgpack.org/

JSON, все-же, если речь не о http, не самое лучшее решение, о XML я вообще молчу :)

Comment: Если события независимые и простые (с событием связано мало данных и структура данных простая), то лучше свой протокол. Мороки меньше.

Comment: ASN.1 забыли. Оно, конечно, местами, для инопланетян, но, все же.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Моя субъективная оценка:

**Protocol Buffers**:

- Поддерживается Google для внутренних сервисов
- Куча готовых реализаций
- Переносимый кроссплатформенный формат
- Бинарный формат (следствие - небольшой размер сообщений)

**XML**:

- Жутко избыточный
- Парсится небыстро

**JSON**:

- Занимает меньше, чем XML
- Сам по себе проще - проще и быстрее парсится

Мой выбор в порядке приоритета:

1. Protocol Buffers
2. JSON
3. XML

В любом случае, не писал бы реализацию ни одного из форматов с нуля.

Comment: Только нет Protobuf RPC реализаций для C.

Comment: @a_gura Кое-что есть: http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/RPC_Example

Comment: Вроде есть, и даже для embedded - [Nanopb](http://koti.kapsi.fi/jpa/nanopb/), только не от Google.

Comment: Это реализация Protocol Buffers, не RPC. Только простенький пример прилагается, как организовать взаимодействие. Хотя это конечно не помеха.

Comment: [Protobuf-C's Remote-Procedure-Call (RPC) Programmer's Reference](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-c/wiki/RPC_API)

Answer (score 4):

Вдобавок ко все недостаткам/плюсам отмеченным [@eigenein](/users/7679/eigenein) я бы еще 1 плюсик в сторону JSON поставил бы то что формат текстовый, что существенно упрощает отладку. Protocol Buffers формат бинарный и в случае чего отлаживаться будет сложно.

Ну а XML - увы не катит ни под каким соусом: избыточный, медленный, громоздкий и все такое.

Мой персональный выбор за JSON.

P.S. Собственный не пишите!

Answer (score 2):

В качестве варианта рассмотрите также [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org)

Answer (score 1):

В таком простейшем случае (всего два устройства) никакой разницы нет. Но использовать XML я бы всё равно не стал. Он уже староват. Ему пора на пенсию. Хуже него только придумывание своего собственного формата.