# Лучший формат общения с сервером для Android

Tags: android, json, xml

Какой формат для Android приложения выбрать, json или xml. Где-то попадалась статья про-то что xml прожорливее по ресурсам. Или всё же разницы нет?

Comment: Возьмите типовые данные, оберните в json и в xml. Сравните затраты на время, объем полученных файлов и прочие характеристики которые вам важны.

Comment: Любой. На этот вопрос нету однозначного ответа.

Comment: Спасибо. Тут нашёл ответ - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/152278/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%80-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-xml-json-protocol-buffers-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B0?rq=1